# Will the garbage collector collect a leaf of a tree that is not accessible anymore but still points to the tree

Tags: java, tree, garbage-collection, binary-search-tree

What happens in this case? will it be collected even though it still has a reference to the tree?

```
class BinarySearchTree {
    TreeNode root;
    /* constructor  including assigning the root*/
    /* other methods of the tree */
    public void example() {
        root = null; /* assume the root already has children */
                         /* we haven't set the parent of the child of the root*/
                          /*to null*/
    }
}

class TreeNode {
    private TreeNode left;
    private TreeNode right;
    private TreeNode parent;

    /* set and get methods */
}
```

Comment: The garbage collector detects circular references. In this case if any node is referenced outside the tree the whole tree will still be in scope. If no node is referenced outside the tree then the tree will go out of scope.

Comment: @BevynQ - Actually, the GC *doesn't* detect circular references.  If an object isn't reachable it isn't reachable, regardless of possible circular references.  GC works based on reachability, not reference counting.

Comment: @HotLicks That would of course depend on the implementation of Java, although I think it certainly runs true for the current SE versions by Oracle.

Comment: @owlstead - It's true of every Sun/Oracle version I've seen, plus the IBM versions.  There were a few experimental versions that used reference counting, et al to a degree, but I don't believe that any ever became "mainstream".  And I don't think that a pure reference counting implementation would meet Java standards -- would have to at least occasionally run a reachability sweep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The garbage collector will collect any object that isn't reachable. IOW, nothing points to it. What it points to itself isn't relevant.

Answer (score 5):

The garbage collector starts from "roots".  These would be several tables anchored by the JVM plus all the references in all the stack frames of all the threads.  Each "root" reference is "traced" to whatever object it addresses, and that object is added to a list of reachable but untraced objects.

After the roots are traced, the list of reachable but untraced objects is examined one at a time and the references in those objects are "traced" to other objects, which are in turn added to the list.

Objects are removed from the list once they've been traced.  Objects that are reached while following a reference and which turn out to already have been touched are not added to a list.

Eventually the list of reachable but untraced objects goes empty, at which point the "mark" phase is done.  Then comes the "sweep" phase -- all objects are scanned, and any which have not been reached are discarded.

This is, of course, an over-simplified version of GC, but it covers pretty much everything.  An object that cannot be "reached" as described above will be "collected" and its space returned to the free space pool.

Answer (score 1):

It will be deleted
Garbage collector collect every object that there is no reference to it, it means that you can not reach it at all

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you are actually populating the tree, the answer is "it depends." As a general rule, if the variable cannot be accessed in the future, it's referred to as an object and gc will take care of it. However, if your tree is set up in such a way that you could later reference the child nodes (like if they had actual variable names), then gc will not help you.

Comment: Meaningless. It depends on whether the object is reachable. Period. If it isn't reachable now it can't magically become reachable in the future. Either the object is referenced or it isn't.